# Spring UI best option

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, view, backend

I starting learn java framework spring and build modern web-application, but at  this moment I dont want use any JS frameworks. In documentation I found two options thymeleaf and WebMvcConfigurer with JSTL.
Which one is more useful and will allow me to understand angular syntax easier in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what type of web-application you are planning on creating. If you are just starting out I would go with Thymeleaf as it is has much more modern server-side features compared to using just JSTL. You can also read more about the setup process for [thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html) using their documentation and integrating it with spring.